# External Drive Shows in Files But is Not Connected and Can't Be Removed

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, unmount

In the file browser I see what appears to be a 3.7GB external flash drive/hard-drive connected to my computer.  There is no 3.7GB drive attached to this computer. There is the usual unmount icon next to this drive and if I select unmount I get a pop-up stating that it is OK to remove the drive.
The drive's properties show a directory in home/media but I cannot delete this directory.  Why is this drive showing in the file browser and how do I get rid of it?  I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: 3.7 GB sounds like an USB stick, do you happen to have any USB periphery connected to your machine via USB?

Comment: Nope, no USB stick.

Comment: You're aware that other USB devices can have memory chips too (for example to hold drivers and the like)? Those would appear then as USB drives too on nautilus. Same is true for external CD/DVD/BR drives.

Comment: ... or mobile phones